# hiding workbook under userform using excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Workbook by name "**archive**" which I am hiding. When opening the workbook, a UserForm pops and asks for password. If the correct password is entered another form opens. The problem is that when the password form opens after clicking on the workbook, I cannot open any other workbook. It seems like all workbooks are hidden and they only open if I enter a password. The code I use is:

```
Private Sub commandbutton2_click()

If TextBox1.Value = "Secret" Then
    MsgBox "Welcome", vbExclamation, "Access granted"
    Me.Hide
    UserForm1.Show
Else
    MsgBox "You have entered an incorrect password!"
    Unload Me
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: do you have a `UserForm_Initialize()` for the first userform? if yes then what do you have in it

Comment: At a guess, the `Workbook_Open` event is showing the password form modally, but that's just a guess since you didn't show enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thank you Shai for you time and assistance,

Comment: I downloaded a template which i edited to suit my needs. I have this Code in Module 1
Sub auto_open()
Application.Visible = False
UserForm2.Show
End Sub

Comment: My apologies, I am not good in english.

Comment: Just to clarify further, UserForm2 opens as the first UserForm. It is from this UserForm that you can call UserForm3 and UserForm1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use the `vbModeless` modal

that is, change your code

```
Sub auto_open()
    Application.Visible = False
    UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

to

```
Sub auto_open()
    Application.Visible = False
    Windows("archive").Visible = False
    UserForm2.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

this will allow you to open other workbooks

Comment: Thank you Arun, let me try that.

Comment: Thank you once Again Arun, it works. God Bless you. Now another problem is this. If i open another workbook it opens together with the hidden workbook.

Comment: try `Windows("archive").Visible = False`

Comment: sorry it gives run-time error '9' subscript out of range

Comment: it should work if the name of your file is `archive`. else it would give the `subscript out of range` error

Comment: thank you soo much, i was missing something but now its working. thank you .

Comment: Arun, i just got another error, Run-time error '1004' methods 'Sheets' of object_' global' failed

Comment: if i debug, its the code, UserForm1.show is highlited
 Private Sub commandbutton2_click()
If TextBox1.Value = "Secret" Then
    MsgBox "Welcome", vbExclamation, "Access granted"
    Me.Hide
    UserForm1.Show
Else
    MsgBox "You have entered an incorrect password!"
    Unload Me
End If

End Sub

Comment: this could be beacuse of your code inside UserForm1 module. To check this, remove the code inside UserForm1 module and open the file. If you don't get any error on button click then the error is because of the UserForm1 code.

Comment: I have one module, i am confused here. how do i upload template for you to see

Comment: i will check it if it is okay for you to sent the file to my mail id `ajarunthomas@gmail.com` or right click the UserForm1->View Code and post the entire code you see there

Comment: Thank you. sending it to you now

Comment: what you have to do is, inside `UserForm_Initialize()` procedure you have to include `Windows("test").Visible = True` in the begining and `Windows("test").Visible = False` at the end of that procedure if `test` is the name of the file. Because here it is looking for the sheet `Data` and it can't find it since its not visible. Looks like you have to do the same in all the procedures where it is referring to the either of the sheets `Data` or `SelectedData`. I have sent you back the file with the corrections inside `UserForm_Initialize()` alone